# How to auto complete variable in Delphi

Tags: delphi

For example: I define a `ClientSocket1` variable in `TForm1`, and use `ClientSocket1` in `TForm1.Button1Click` procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if ClientSocke{ready to completion} then

end;
```

I press `Ctrl+Space` , But System Input Method was shown instead of completion，

please looking following gif animation screen record for explanation(please note the right bottom corner of the input method activity)

[image]

In Lazarus , I can use `Ctrl+W` to complete related variable in Unit, However I cannot do the same operation in Delphi, and the Delphi `CTRL+Space` is conflict with system input method.

Comment: It is looking for a Boolean or something that can evaluate to a Boolean. Try self.ClientSoc instead and you will see it work.

Comment: Is there some way to change CTRL+SPACE to another shortcut? because it conflict with system input method switch shortcut

Comment: In Tools -> Options -> Editor options -> Key mappings you can select different standard key mappings for the entire IDE. I'm not aware of any built-in option that lets you select a key mapping of a specific functionality only, but maybe there are IDE extensions for that.

Comment: Without having tried it: Isn't Ctrl+J an alias for Ctrl+Space?

Comment: @dummzeuch no, `Ctrl+J` calls `Templates pop-up menu` not the `Code Completion pop-up window`. [See this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Editor_Options). Pay attention to `Editor SpeedSetting` item in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default hotkeys for Delphi code editor there are few available presets in `Tools -> Options -> Editor options - Key mappings`.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Key_Mappings

It is possible to install additional presets through `Open Tools API`.

Amongst the provided presets are also `New IDE Emacs` and `New IDE Clasic` which are such custom key mappings installed into Delphi IDE through the `Open Tools API`.

According to documentation you can find ready examples for changing these in `Samples > Delphi > VCL > ToolsAPI > Editor KeyBinding`, but I can't find such example on my computer. Perhaps it is because I only own Professional edition of Delphi.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/New_IDE_Classic_and_New_IDE_Emacs_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score -1):

it is bug in Delphi IDE,
only close the Delphi and restart it again

Comment: This is not a bug in Delphi IDE. When using Chinese as input language in Windows the keyboard shortcut CTRL+Space for switching between Chinese (traditional) and Chinese (Simplified) https://superuser.com/a/480723